# Difference between $(document).on('click') and $('p[class="classname"]').on('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an  element like this

```
<p class="classname">click</p>
```

I am using two ways to `click` on this `p` tag

1.

```
$(document).on('click','p',function(){
   //
});
```

2.

```
$('p[class="classname"]').on('click',function(){
   //
});
```

There is no issue on working of this. These both methods working fine.

But what is the difference between these methods.

Comment: It is called [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) which is used to support dynamically created elements... also there is difference in the selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer focus' on the difference between the two uses of `.on()` described in the question. Not the difference between the selectors.

The difference between the two is that the first example

```
$(document).on('click','p',function(){
   //
});
```

Makes use of event bubbling (or event delegation). This is particularly useful when you have applications that heavily manipulate the DOM that remove and add lots of elements. (Angular or Backbone applications for example that use their respective routers to switch views).

Event bubbling allows you to bind to a lower level, static element but have the event target a nested element that can be removed and added as many times as you wish and maintain the event binding.

Your second example

```
$('p[class="classname"]').on('click',function(){
   //
});
```

Binds an event directly to the element. If this element never changes this is fine. If it is removed at any point this binding is lost and would need to be redeclared once it has been re-added to the DOM. This can be a tedious process to say the least. As a result I always use your first option even on 'undynamic' elements just in case I change my mind.

Answer (score 1):

When your `p` element inserted dynamically then following will not work

```
$('p[class="classname"]').on('click',function(){
   //
});
```

And when `p` element inserted dynamically or initially then following will work in both case.

```
$(document).on('click','p',function(){
   //
});
```

**[Reference](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**

Comment: There is a diff between selectors as well in both cases, first would match all <p> with class 'classname' where as second would match all <p>. But I guess this is not what op intended to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Another benefit of the first example

```
$(document).on('click','p',function(){
   //
});
```

is that it binds one event handler to `$(document)` to handle all click events to `p` elements.

The second example

```
$('p[class="classname"]').on('click',function(){
   //
});
```

will bind one event handler per matching element, which could potentially be a lot of handlers. And the more event handlers you have, the slower the page will be.

Also note that you do not have to let the events bubble all the way to document. You probably would want to handle them at the earliest possible stage, which is the first common parent.

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)